# Is there a way to render ReactiveList conditionally

Tags: reactivesearch

I'm working with [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/result-components/reactivelist.html) and trying to figure out how I can render a ReactiveList component conditionally?

For example, if I only want to render a ReactiveList component that has an actor's birthday data (day, month, year, city, country, etc) if user enters a query like "when was tom cruise born"

I have a couple ReactiveList components rendering different types of results but am not sure how to do this one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ReactiveList in v3 uses [Render Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern which comes with callback function and has `(data, loading, error, ...)` as it params.

So based on the data you can conditionally render any component.

For more information on `render` prop, you can check [docs](https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/result/reactivelist/)